What's the role of Python in ArcGIS?
I have a series of instructions to solve a certain question using ArcGIS and Python.
I have been a programmer with C# and node.js but I am absolutely zero knowledge about this ArcGIS Pro.
Number 1 instruction is:
Prior creating python file, I have to import HomeSale_2024 from somewhere.
Create a header using markdown to create a summary of what the project will include.
...
...
I have a copy of this so called gdb? But I don't know what exactly I will do to like import/export, whatsoever.
I can only imagine what Python is because I know it's a programming language but how can I connect it with the gdb file I have here and run? Please help.
